# How to add image in GL_Line in openGLES (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Currently i am working in simple game application, using GL_Line to draw a line and its working fine, then i tried to add (Anchor) image, at the end of the line. but i cannot know, How to fix this?, so can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you draw a textured quad to get this done?
You can just glTranslate to the end of the line and draw the quad.

Comment: can you please give an example?

Comment: There are no GL_QUAD in OpenGL ES, isn't it?